# Python Convert a string of tuple list into a tuple list

Tags: python, string, list, tuples

input : a string = "[('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656)]"

desired output: a tuple list [('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656)]

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Shinratensei, you can use ast

```
import ast
output = ast.literal_eval("[('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656), ('0.0.0.0',5656)]")
# [('0.0.0.0', 5656), ('0.0.0.0', 5656), ('0.0.0.0', 5656), ('0.0.0.0', 5656)]
```